# CSS "calc()" function returns invalid

Tags: css, css-position, calc

I have a div element that I want to put a button in, and I want to use the calc() function to move the button down relative to the position of that div element, but it returns as an "Invalid property value" according to chrome dev tools.

```
#rArrow {
    top: calc(inherit + 80px);
    height: 76px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 28px;
}
```

Comment: Try leaving out the inherit and see what happens, and read up about calc eg on MDN, or investigate translate or margin etc depending on your use case. If still stuck please put code into the question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

calc() is suppose to calculate using a mathematical expression like `-`, `+`, `*` or `/`. According to your problem the inherit keyword can only exist alone as a value in a property declaration. It cannot be used with functions like `calc()` either.

Answer (score 1):

### The Real Problem

It's already been mentioned from previous answers ([fadzrinmadu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919473/2813224) and [Samitha Wijesekara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919423/2813224)) why `inherit` isn't a valid value for `calc()`. I will address your actual problem that lead you to try to adjust the `top` property in the first place. I'm assuming that the distance between the top of the `<button>` and the top of the containing `<div>` (`<menu>` in example) was not 80px.

### The Explanation

A tag that has `position: absolute` measures all of it's positions (`top`, `bottom`, `right`, and `left`) in relation to it's nearest ancestor tag that has `position: relative`. If there's no ancestor tag with `position: relative`, then the distance is set between the edge of the page and the edge of the tag with `position: absolute`.

### The Solution

Add `position: relative` to the containing `<div>`

In the example below there are two `<menu>` tags, each with a button.

- The `<menu>` on the left has `position: relative`
- The `<menu>` on the right has `position: static` (that's default and it's the same as not having `position` at all).

```css
/* ✳️ Most Relevant */

/* For Demo Only */

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

menu {
  position: relative; /* ✳️ */
  width: 84px;
  height: 236px;
  border: 1px dashed tomato;
}


/* For Demo Only */

.static {
  position: static;
}

.rArrow {
  position: absolute; /* ✳️ */
  top: 80px;          /* ✳️ */
  width: 28px;
  height: 76px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Optional */

.rArrow::before {
  content: '▶';
  display: block;
  margin: 2.5px 0 0 -9px;
  color: magenta;
  transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(0.5);
}


/* For Demo Only */

b {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}


/* For Demo Only */

b::before {
  content: '⇕80px';
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-family: Consolas;
  color: #930;
  transform: scaleY(2) scaleX(0.5);
}


/* For Demo Only */

.offset {
  margin-top: -24px
}
```

```html
<main>
  <menu>
    <b><!--For Demo Only--></b>
    <button class='rArrow'></button>
  </menu>

  <menu class='static'>
    <b class='offset'>
    <!--For Demo Only-->
    </b>
    <button class='rArrow'></button>
  </menu>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "initial" value top/left/right/bottom it means the value becomes "auto". the calc() function in css only accepts values "length", "frequency", "angle", "time", "percentage", "number", or "integer" is allowed.

ref : [CSS Calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)